Flutter mek_stripe_terminal: ^3.8.0 use for stripe tap to pay gets error
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform jackson-core-2.16.1.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.16.1) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/rased/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.16.1/9456bb3cdd0f79f91a5f730a1b1bb041a380c91f/jackson-core-2.16.1.jar.
> Failed to transform '/Users/rased/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.16.1/9456bb3cdd0f79f91a5f730a1b1bb041a380c91f/jackson-core-2.16.1.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 65. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
Suggestions:
- Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
- If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

when i going to implement this mek_stripe_terminal: ^3.8.0 code then gets error please help me any one
Thanks in advance .
